# Can we have multiple path/directories for fonts in linux?

Tags: fonts, directory, paths

Is there anyway to have multiple directories for loading fonts in Linux distros? Or loading the fonts from a directory inside `.fonts` such as `.fonts/DIRECTORY`?

I have two sets of fonts, and I don't want to mix them in `.fonts` directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can organize your fonts in subdirectories under your dedicated fonts directories (e.g. `.fonts` or `.local/share/fonts`). These fonts all will be picked up.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. I wanted to add have multiple directories inside these paths you mentioned above. For example: `.fonts/English` and `.fonts/Korean`. I don't want to mix them in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can have directories inside `.fonts` directory and still the fonts will show up.
If it doesn't work for you, maybe you need a log-out and log-in or reboot and done. The fonts inside the other directories will show up also.